# Some issues with Sphinx and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Here is the case:

I have a big table in my database - 3.6 GB and 1,7M rows. Selecting with limit and offset from the table is extremely slow and often results in Error 504. Table is MyISAM, has multiple indexes and will be updated.

That's why I decided to use Sphinx to list the contents of the table - in some cases without query (all the rows), in some cases with query - and it works like a charm. The speed is amazing.

But here's the problem - without a query only the first 1,000 results are returned. Even if I call it with `$this->SetLimits(41, 24);` which should return me the results with id from `984` to `1008`, but the last result I get is id 1,000. I tried changing the value in my `/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf`, restarted the service, but no success.
Also, is that a good idea? I mean, will it slow down the performance noticeably? Any suggestions on how to do this?

And here is another question:

In my `sphinx.conf` I selected the columns I want to use for search/order and they all appear in the `[matches]` section. Since I don't use them, they only take memory and (I guess) reduce the performance to some extend. I only use `id` in my application. Is it possible to search/order by these columns, but exclude them from `[matches]`?

My `sphinx.conf`

```
source test {

  type          = mysql

  sql_host      = localhost
  sql_user      = root
  sql_pass      = password
  sql_db        = database
  sql_port      = 3306

  sql_query     = \
  SELECT id, name,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date, views, rating \
  FROM table \
  WHERE active = 1

  sql_field_string      = name
  sql_attr_timestamp    = date
  sql_attr_uint         = views
  sql_attr_uint         = rating

  sql_query_info        = SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id

}

index test {

  source            = test
  path              = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test
  docinfo           = extern
  charset_type      = utf-8

}

searchd {

  listen            = 9312
  log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  query_log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file          = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
  max_matches       = 10000 # I tried changing this to 10,000 - no result
  seamless_rotate   = 1
  preopen_indexes   = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  binlog_path       = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there's per-query max-matches setting as well, and it defaults to 1000.

in sphinx.conf you could set something like

```
max_matches = 10000
```

or, add max_matches to your query

```
$this->SetLimits(41, 24, 10000);
```

> Note that there are two places where max_matches limit is enforced.
>   Per-query limit is controlled by this API call, but there also is
>   per-server limit controlled by max_matches setting in the config file.
>   To prevent RAM usage abuse, server will not allow to set per-query
>   limit higher than the per-server limit.

Comment: As you can see, I have `max_matches` in my `searchd` section and it is set to 10,000

Comment: Okay, I tried this and now I get 10,000 results, but if I set the third parameter to 10,001 - nothing is returned. `max_matches` is now set to 100,000. Is there a way to go higher?

Comment: So, did it work correctly? Here some more info: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/api-func-setlimits.html  .

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. Yes, it worked great! Do you have any idea how to proceed with the second part of my question?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part look at the `->SetSelect()` function.