# Sphinx RT Index - Is there any way to set max_matches in Index definition

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxql

I am using SphinxQL for querying RT Index and it contains multi million records. My problem is when i tried to query second page of result set

```
$searches = $prepStatement->query("select * from searchAnalytics limit $offset,$rowsPerPage")->execute();
```

it throws the error

```
offset out of bounds (offset=1000, max_matches=1000) [ select * from searchAnalytics limit 1000,1000]
```

Can somebody please help me to get out of this problem?
Is there any way to set max_matches in Index definition?

My index is

```
type = rt
rt_mem_limit = 1024M
path = /Users/vimson/projects/sphinx/data/searchAnalytics

rt_attr_string = SessionId
rt_attr_timestamp = Time
rt_field = Query
rt_attr_string = Query
rt_field = SearchLocation
rt_attr_string = SearchLocation
rt_attr_uint = Location
rt_attr_uint = CourseType
rt_attr_uint = SearchType
rt_attr_uint = CourseCount
rt_attr_multi = Courses
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some issues with Sphinx and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751138/some-issues-with-sphinx-and-php)

Comment: I am using RT Index and SphinxQL. I can solve this problem using the query `select * from searchAnalytics limit $offset,$rowsPerPage OPTION max_matches=10000000`. But if we can set this in RT index it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set query time with `OPTION` as noted in comments.

*(There used to be one in the 'searchd' section of the config file (not per index) - but it just applied a cap, would still need to use the query time parameter anyway)*

Note its best to set it dynamically...

```
$max = max(1000,$offset+$rowsPerPage+300);
$qu = "... limit $offset,$rowsPerPage OPTION max_matches=$max";
```

rather than **just** setting a stupidly high number.